# add filter to a UserView

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Just played with flaskadmin and the CRUD with relationships is working pretty good for an Admin View, but what I need is a restricted user view. Is it somehow possible to create a Userview, so a logged in user can only see his Data and not the data from Users? (also not the other users)

I am searching for a way to add something like `"WHERE id = 1"` to each dbsession query.

Thanks for Help!
Ms

My code looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://xx:xyz@localhost/db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users' # portal user
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    data = db.relationship("Data", back_populates="users")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.email)

class UsersView(ModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ['active']

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user_email = db.relationship("Users", back_populates="email")
    somesecrets = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)


admin.add_view(UsersView(Users, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Data, db.session))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [`get_query`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.get_query) and `get_query_count` methods of your `ModelView` class.

For example:

```
class DataView(ModelView):

    def get_query(self):
        current_user_id = get_current_user_id()
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(Data.user_id == current_user_id)

    def get_count_query(self):
        current_user_id = get_current_user_id()
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model).filter(Data.user_id == current_user_id)

...

admin.add_view(UsersView(Users, db.session))
admin.add_view(DataView(Data, db.session))
```

If you are using something like [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) or [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it is easy to get the current logged in user.